# Artifacts mentioned in secondary-artifacts section not getting uploaded to s3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-codepipeline

I have created a codePipeline project through which my application get build using maven and it's artifacts are uploaded to s3. I'm trying to upload multiple artifacts as a single zip file to s3 bucket through codebuild. Below is my sample buildspec.yml file

```
version: 0.2 

phases: 
  install: 
    runtime-versions: 
      java: openjdk8 
    commands: 
      - apt update -y && apt install maven -y 
      - echo Install phase started on `date` 
      - echo Install phase ended on `date` 
  pre_build: 
    commands: 
      - echo Pre_build phase started on `date` 
      - bash pipelines/aws/scripts/onCheckout.sh 
      - echo Pre_build phase ended on `date` 
  build: 
    commands: 
      - echo Build phase started on `date` 
      - bash pipelines/aws/scripts/onBuild.sh 
      - echo Build phase ended on `date` 
  post_build: 
    commands: 
      - echo Post_build phase started on `date` 
      - bash pipelines/aws/scripts/onPackage.sh 
      - bash pipelines/aws/scripts/onPublish.sh 
      - bash pipelines/aws/scripts/onPromote.sh 
      - echo Post_build phase ended on `date` 
      - echo $CODEBUILD_SRC_DIR 
artifacts: 
  files: 
    - pipelines/**/* 
    - target/spring-petclinic-2.0.0.jar 
  base-directory: $CODEBUILD_SRC_DIR 
secondary-artifacts: 
  artifact1: 
    files: 
      - pipelines/aws/appspec.yml 
    base-directory: $CODEBUILD_SRC_DIR   
    discard-paths: yes
```

codebuild-output:

```
https://forums.aws.amazon.com/ 2019/05/24 12:00:27 Phase complete: POST_BUILD State: SUCCEEDED 
https://forums.aws.amazon.com/ 2019/05/24 12:00:27 Phase context status code: Message: 
https://forums.aws.amazon.com/ 2019/05/24 12:00:27 Expanding base directory path: $CODEBUILD_SRC_DIR 
https://forums.aws.amazon.com/ 2019/05/24 12:00:27 Assembling file list 
https://forums.aws.amazon.com/ 2019/05/24 12:00:27 Expanding /codebuild/output/src289881682/src 
https://forums.aws.amazon.com/ 2019/05/24 12:00:27 Expanding artifact file paths for base directory /codebuild/output/src289881682/src 
https://forums.aws.amazon.com/ 2019/05/24 12:00:27 Assembling file list 
https://forums.aws.amazon.com/ 2019/05/24 12:00:27 Expanding pipelines/**/* 
https://forums.aws.amazon.com/ 2019/05/24 12:00:27 Expanding target/spring-app-2.0.0.jar 
https://forums.aws.amazon.com/ 2019/05/24 12:00:27 Found 52 file(s) 
https://forums.aws.amazon.com/ 2019/05/24 12:00:28 Phase complete: UPLOAD_ARTIFACTS State: SUCCEEDED 
https://forums.aws.amazon.com/ 2019/05/24 12:00:28 Phase context status code: Message:
```

Artifacts mentioned in secondary-artifacts are completely ignored due to unknown reasons, Am I missing any parameters?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the CodeBuild "Artifacts" configuration, there is an "Add Artifact" button.

You need to click that and reference your secondary artifact to get it to upload to S3 as well.